# form name in ng-repeat and pass form name in ng-click function to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

I am having form in ng-repeat with different form names.

i want to pass the form when some button clicked inside form.

When am calling like below

```
checkSaveDisable(updateProductSale_{{productIndex}}) it throwing some angular js error.
```

It might be am passing the angular expressions inside the function call. How can i pass the form which contains dynamic name in function.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="productSale in productSales" class="existingProductSales" ng-init="productIndex=$index">
<form name="updateProductSale_{{productIndex}}" novalidate>

---------------//

<button class="btn btn-default save-btn save-sale" ng-disabled="checkSaveDisable(updateProductSale_{{productIndex}})" >Save</button>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can use `ngForm` directive to handle `forms` inside `ngRepeat`.

Comment: @developer033 tried to use ngForm but want to pass dynamic form object  to javascript

Comment: For what do you need to pass the form?

Answer (score 0):

updateProductSale_{{productIndex}} is a string value, right? If so, to pass the string value as an argument, try to use

```
ng-disabled="checkSaveDisable('updateProductSale_{{productIndex}}')"
```

**UPDATE**: Okay, what if you use the following?

```
ng-disabled="checkSaveDisable('updateProductSale_' + {{productIndex}})"
```

```js
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.productSales = ['Form1', 'Form2'];
  
  $scope.click = function(val) {
    alert(val);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-repeat="productSale in productSales">
        <form name="updateProductSale_{{$index}}" novalidate>
            <button class="btn btn-default save-btn save-sale" ng-click="click('updateProductSale_' + $index)" >Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: updateProductSale_ is a constant value, {{productIndex}} is a dynamic value, try to pass the concatenated result in the function, please see the updated answer. I hope the idea is clear. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: @Antipod it won't pass the form object.It just passing the string

Comment: @SivaRajini aha, I see. What is a form object? Is it an object in the controller scope? I would say no. I do not see how you set values inside the form, you did not provide the code. I would bind values in the form to a model which will be an array, pass the index of an element to find it and then work with it in the function. Another option which I do not prefer  is to pass the prefix as first argument and the dynamic part (when it is an object, not plain value) as the second argument. Then I would construct the form name and use angular.element function to find the form.